# unsigned characters and sprintf() C

Tags: c, printf

I have this code:

```
int main(){

char buffer[1024];
char port = 1;
int length = 255;
char * record = "$TAG ,0 ,89 ,0, 1\n";

if(length < 0 || length > 255){
    printf("Error - length out of range for an unsigned char.\n");
    exit(1);
}

snprintf(buffer, 1024, "%c%c%s", port, (unsigned char) length, record);

int port_rc     = buffer[0];
int length_rc   = buffer[1]; 

printf("port_rc: %d\n",port_rc);
printf("length_rc: %d\n",length_rc);

return 0;
```

}

Output when I run it:

`port_rc: 1
length_rc: -1`

I think I am missing something here in terms of snprintf() as i'm not seeing the 255 value when reading the array it created back. My guess is that snprintf() is promoting the variable 'length' to an int or something. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The first char of `"255"` is `'2'`  which has the value `50` in ascii.

Comment: @tkausl What keeps you from making an answer?

Comment: Will you *ever* get `255` by using a different format specifier? The `char` is presumed signed, since you use an `(unsigned char)` cast rather than `(char)`. So you would get `-1`.

Comment: `buffer[1]` has type `char`, it is literally impossible for it to store 255 (assuming your system has plain char as signed)

Comment: @M.M - yes that is why I was trying to use an usigned char. I've figured it out and you can see my solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `sprintf()` to store `255` into the buffer. The buffer argument to `sprintf()` is a `char` array. Whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` by default is implementation-defined; see [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). If  `255` is greater than `CHAR_MAX`, trying to store `255` results in undefined behavior; if the implementation defaults to `signed` then `CHAR_MAX` will probably be `127`.

I suggest not using `sprintf()` to store numbers into the buffer. Declare it as:

```
unsigned char buffer[127];
```

Then you can do:

```
buffer[0] = port;
buffer[1] = length;
snprintf((char *)(buffer + 2), sizeof buffer - 2, "%s", record);
```

Comment: Right, but doing that does not return 255 in the variable 'length_rc'. Please see modified code above. And if I change 'length' to 127 (largest signed character number) output is produced as expected.

Comment: I see the problem. The buffer is `char[]`, not `unsigned char[]`. So `buffer[1]` is signed. Storing `255` into the buffer results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can do this more safely.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Bamar - i've incorporated your solution. My post is updated to reflect the working changes.

Comment: You should put the working solution in an answer, not the question.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

*"Be careful, though,"* when judging such a "solution."

In my humble, the root problem – in your original post - is that the variables `port_rc` and `length_rc` should have been declared as *unsigned* integers. You do not want a value such as `$FF` to be erroneously "sign-extended" to become `$FFFFFFFF == -1` ...

Your "solution" is quite different from the original because, as you see, it now *stores into* both `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]` before then retrieving and examining those values!

Comment: I agree but I do make sure the valid return is 0-255 to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
int main(){

unsigned char buffer[1024];
char port = 1;
int length = 255;
char * record = "$TAG ,0 ,89 ,0, 1\n";

if(length < 0 || length > 255){
    printf("Error - length out of range for an unsigned char.\n");
    exit(1);
}

buffer[0] = port;
buffer[1] = length;
snprintf((char *)(buffer), sizeof buffer - 2, "%c%c%s", port,length,record);

int port_rc     = buffer[0];
int length_rc   = buffer[1]; 
char char_first = buffer[2];

printf("port_rc: %d\n",port_rc);
printf("length_rc: %d\n",length_rc);
printf("char_first: %c\n",char_first);


return 0;
```

}

RETURNS:

`port_rc: 1
length_rc: 255
char_first: $`